# I am trying to understand how to share read-only objects with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing, copy-on-write

I am trying to understand how to share read-only objects with multiprocessing. Sharing `bigset` when it is a global variable works fine:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

bigset = set(xrange(pow(10, 7)))

def worker(x):
  return x in bigset

def main():
  pool = Pool(5)
  print all(pool.imap(worker, xrange(pow(10, 6))))
  pool.close()
  pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

`htop` shows that the parent process uses 100% CPU and 0.8% memory, while the workload is distributed evenly among the five children processes: each is using 10% CPU and 0.8% memory. It's all good.

But the numbers start going crazy if I move `bigset` inside `main`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial    

def worker(x, l):
  return x in l

def main():
  bigset = set(xrange(pow(10, 7)))
  _worker = partial(worker, l=bigset)
  pool = Pool(5)
  print all(pool.imap(_worker, xrange(pow(10, 6))))
  pool.close()
  pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Now `htop` shows 2 or 3 processes jumping up and down between 50% and 80% CPU, while the remaining processes use less than 10% CPU. And while the parent process still uses 0.8% memory, now all children use 1.9% memory.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `bigset` as an argument, it is pickled by the parent process and unplickled by the children processes.<sup>[1][2]</sup>

Pickling and unpickling a large set requires a lot of time. This explains why you are seeing few processes doing their job: the parent process has to pickle a lot of big objects, and the children have to wait for it. The parent process is a bottleneck.

Pickling parameters implies that parameters have to be sent to processes. Sending data from a process to another requires system calls, which is why you are not seeing 100% CPU usage by the user space code. Part of the CPU time is spent on kernel space.<sup>[3]</sup>

Pickling objects and sending them to subprocesses also implies that: 1. you need memory for the pickle buffer; 2. each subprocess gets a copy of `bigset`. This is why you are seeing an increase in memory usage.

Instead, when `bigset` is a global variable, it is not sent anywhere (unless you are using a [start method](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) other than *fork*). It is just inherited as-is by subprocesses, using the usual copy-on-write rules of `fork()`.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. In case you don't know what "pickling" means: [pickle](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pickle.html) is one of the standard Python protocols to transform arbitrary Python objects to and from a byte sequence.
2. `imap()` & co. use [queues](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) behind the scenes, and queues work by pickling/unpickling objects.
3. I tried running your code (with `all(pool.imap(_worker, xrange(100)))` in order to make the process faster) and I got: 2 minutes user time, 13 seconds system time. That's almost 10% system time.